# Compute the First Homology Group of the Klein Bottle

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, quotient-group

I am trying to compute the first homology group of the *Klein bottle* $K$ using its descomposition in two Mobius bands $M_1,M_2$ by using the reduced *Mayer-Vietoris sequence*:
$$\dots \longrightarrow \tilde H_1(M_1\cap M_2) \stackrel{\Phi}{\longrightarrow}\tilde H_1(M_1)\oplus \tilde H_1(M_2)\longrightarrow\tilde H_1(K)\longrightarrow 0 \longrightarrow \dots$$
The sequence is exact, so the first homology group of the Klein bottle must be given by:
$$\tilde H_1(K)\cong \frac{\tilde H_1(M_1)\oplus \tilde H_1(M_2)}{\textrm{im}\,\Phi}.$$
Lets compute the image of $\Phi$. Denote by $b,a_1,a_2$ the generators of $\tilde H_1(M_1\cap M_2)$, $\tilde H_1(M_1)$, $\tilde H_1(M_2)$ respectively and recall that $\Phi$ is given by the induced maps $i_1^\star,i_2^\star$ of the inclusions $i_1:M_1\cap M_2\hookrightarrow M_1$ and $i_2:M_1\cap M_2\hookrightarrow M_2$ as follows:
$$\Phi(b)=\big(i_1^\star(b),i_2^\star(b)\big).$$
It is clear that 1-degree loops in $M_1\cap M_2$ are mapped to 2-degree loops in the Mobius band by the inclusions. This implies:
$$\Phi(b)=(a_1^2,a_2^2),$$
Thus $\textrm{im}\, (\Phi)\cong \langle a_1^2\rangle \oplus \langle a_2^2\rangle$. From here, **I dont know how to compute the quotient**:
$$\tilde H_1(K)\cong \frac{\tilde H_1(M_1)\oplus \tilde H_1(M_2)}{\textrm{im}\,\Phi}\cong \frac{\langle a_1\rangle \oplus \langle a_2\rangle}{ \langle a_1^2\rangle \oplus \langle a_2^2\rangle}$$
This is probabily a very basic fact of group theory.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You're computing the quotient group $\Bbb Z^2/\langle(2,2)\rangle$. In general, we have $\Bbb Z^2/\langle(a,b)\rangle\cong\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z_{\gcd(a,b)}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Kevin.S. Do you know where can I see a proof of this statement? Sorry for my limited knowledge of groups

Comment: You might find the second spoiler of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4233879/disk-glued-to-a-torus-classifying-the-resulting-spaces-how-where-to-begin/4234030#4234030) post useful, even though the question itself is not about group theory.