# Computation of fundamental group $\pi_1(T\cup_f B^2)$ with attaching map $f:S^1\to T$ defined by $f(z)=(z,-z)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I need some help with the following question:

Let $f:S^1\to T=S^1\times S^1$ be a map to a torus defined by the formula $f(z)=(z,-z)$. Compute the fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$ where $X=T\cup_f B^2$ is obtained from $T$ by attaching a 2-disk along $f$.

I'm not sure how the attaching map plays a role in this computation. Under normal circumstances, I would argue that $\pi_1(T\cup B^2)=\mathbb{Z}$. Does the attaching map affect the fundamental group? How do I go about computing this fundamental group? What if the attaching map was $f(z)=(-z,z)$ or $f(z)=(z,z)$?

Comment: This is already covered in [my answer to another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4234030/724407). The point is that attaching a 2-disk introduces additional relations in the fundamental group which can be seen by Seifert van Kampen's theorem.